# Выбрать правильный компонент

Tags: c#, winforms

Какой программный компонент Visual Studio оптимально подходит для вывода текстовых данных, изображений? Целесообразно ли использовать для этого такой компонент, как WebBrowser?

Comment: Что значит _программный компонент Visual Studio_?

Comment: @AGS17, то есть компонент панели элементов

Comment: смотря какая цель, можно и Panel поместить и в него различные компоненты добавлять, можно и грид использовать, а можно и web browser